# Match lines between two patters using sed just once

Tags: awk, sed, grep, pattern-matching

Given: `sed -e '/pattern1/,/pattern2/!d' file.org`

How can I match the first occurrence of the lines between pattern1 and pattern2, but not the rest?

For example:

```
pattern1
aaaa
pattern2
pattern1
bbb
pattern
```

should output:
`aaa`

Alternatives solutions (using `grep`, `awk` or whatever) are welcomed.

Comment: @don_crissti: almost, I want the same, but excluding the two patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat input
a
b
c
a
b
c
$ sed -n '/a/,/c/p;/c/q' input
a
b
c
```

Searches for the range to print, and then quits after seeing the first 'end' marker.

`awk` makes it a little easier to exclude the start and end points:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { p=0 }  /c/ { p=0; exit } p {print} /a/ { p=1 }' input
b
```

Comment: I want this, but excluding the matched patterns. I could grep lines not containing them, but a one command solution would be more appropriate.